# Using Pointer Strings gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, pointers

The task was mainly to use pointers to input a string and slice it at places where there is a '\' character and output them in separate lines, using pointers. The program runs fine when I use arrays instead of pointers. However using pointers to store strings give the message "Segmentation fault". The code is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
char *name;
char *sep[100];
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
scanf("%[^\n]s", name);

for(i = 0; (*(name+i)) != '\0'; i++) {
    if((*(name+i)) == '\\') {
        *((*(sep+k))+j) = '\0';
        j = 0;
        k++;
    } else {
        *((*(sep+k))+j) = *(name+i);
        j++;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", *(sep+i));
}

return 0;
}
```

It would be awesome if you could point out what and where the problem is, instead of giving me an alternative solution. TIA.

Comment: You must allocate space for each pointer in `sep` array. The same for `name` var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pointers are null pointers.you are invoking undefined behavior by using them without assigning them to allocated memory.Allocate memory to them so that you can use them correctly and store words separated by \.Also,you can use `[]` instead of `*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[256];
    char *sep[100];
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 100 ; n++ )
    {
        sep[n] = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    scanf(" %255[^\n]s", name);

    for(i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if( name[i] == '\\')
        {
            sep[k][j] = '\0';
            j = 0;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            sep[k][j] = name[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    sep[k][j] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i <= k ; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",sep[i]);
    }
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 100 ; n++ )
    {
        free(sep[n]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the problem was in the assignment of pointer memory. Unfortunately, I totally forgot about malloc(). 

Thumbs up man.

Comment: 'name' is not *necessarily* NULL, nor are the elements of `sep`.  But they are uninitialized, which is comparably bad.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
 scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
```

`name` is an unintialized pointer. It does not point to any valid memory location. You need to allocate memory before you can use it.

The same goes out for `sep` array, too.

You can consider using an array for this purpose or see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) of `malloc()` if you want to stick to a pointer.

FWIW, using an unitialized pointer can lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate space for your pointers to avoid undefined behaviour: you cannot use a pointer without initializing it.

```
int main() {
   char *name = malloc(MAX_DIM_OF_NAME+1);
   char *sep[100];

   for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
      sep[i] = malloc(MAX_DIM_OF_NAME+1);

   ....
```

Answer (score -1):

You call `scanf` with an uninitialized `name`.